# How to web scrape color palettes from a color palette website with Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to web scrape a list of color palettes with their rgb values from a color palette design website. The HTML code looks like this for each color palette:

```
<div class = "item block shadow">    
  <div class="palette">
       <div class="place c4" style="background-color: rgb(34, 14, 36);">...</div>
       <div class="place c3" style="background-color: rgb(52, 32, 86);">...</div>
       <div class="place c2" style="background-color: rgb(84, 84, 197);">...</div>
       <div class="place c1" style="background-color: rgb(99, 156, 217);">...</div>
```

When I web scraped this information on Python, the output didn't show the "style=..." part:

```
[<div class="palette">
<div class="place c4"><a href=""></a><span></span></div>
<div class="place c3"><a href=""></a><span></span></div>
<div class="place c2"><a href=""></a><span></span></div>
<div class="place c1"><a href=""></a><span></span></div>
</div>]
```

Is there a way to extract the information I'm looking for? Thanks in advance.

edit: here's my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://colorhunt.co/palettes/popular')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
repo = soup.find(class_="item block shadow")
repo_list = repo.find_all(class_='palette')
```

Comment: post the scraper code.

Comment: Post the URL of website

Comment: People keep asking for the same problem for almost every web-scraping question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not that you scrape the wrong part, it's that you scrape the page before it's done loading.This page is https://colorhunt.co/ btw.

When you run this command `page = requests.get('https://colorhunt.co/palettes/popular')`. What you're getting is a raw HTML file with no JS execution yet   .Take a look at `script` tag of the html you're getting. You'll see lot of JS code is for rendering elements especially in the `palette` class sections you're trying to get. Thus , all of the colors are not in your scraped content.

Solution: use a library that simulate as if you're browsing the web from the code, run the webpage, wait for it to finish, when it is done, scrape. I learn JS so my choice is `puppeteer`, there is also a python equivalent called `pyppeteer` but I think there are more libraries like these.

Hope this answer will help although it's been over a year since you asked. I ran into this problem and no legitimate answer is found anywhere so this will probably save some others' time. Better be late than nothing :)